# Type "Any" has no subscript members despite casting as AnyObject on Swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode

Recently converted code from earlier version of swift to swift 3. Got a lot of errors signifying that type "any" has no subscript members and I thought this could be fixed by casting as AnyObject, but the error persists (and therefore the code I post here does not have this cast in it). Here is the relevant code:

```
func textfieldTextWasChanged(_ newText: String, parentCell: CustomCell) {
        let parentCellIndexPath = tblExpandable.indexPath(for: parentCell)

        var address = ""

        address = "\(newText)"

        // TODO: add a pin to the map from input address
        cellDescriptors[0][11].setValue(address, forKey: "primaryTitle")
        location = cellDescriptors[0][11]["primaryTitle"]! as! String
        tblExpandable.reloadData()
    }
```

Note that cellDescriptors is defined earlier in the code as an `NSMutableArray`. The error shows up right after `cellDescriptors[0]` in both lines that it is in. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: What does the declaration of `cellDescriptors` look like?

Comment: Why don't you cast it to the correct type? e.g. `[String: String]` or  `[String: AnyObject]`?

Comment: @TomHarrington it is declared as such: `var cellDescriptors: NSMutableArray!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using more than one subscript operator, because presumably this is something like an array of arrays. But `NSMutableArray`'s subscript operator returns `Any`. As a result, `cellDescriptors[0]` is `Any`. You try to use `[11]` on the result, but `Any` doesn't accept subscripts because it's `Any`, not a collection type.

Casting to `AnyObject` doesn't help because `AnyObject` is also not a collection type.

What you should do is cast `cellDescriptors[0]` to something that accepts subscripts. The right choice depends on what kind of data you're storing in `cellDescriptors`, but it's presumably some kind of collection, probably an array type.

Another approach would be to change `cellDescriptors` to be a Swift type instead of `NSMutableArray`. You could specifically declare the types for each part of your data structure, and then type casting wouldn't be needed.

Comment: I understand the explanation of your answer, but do not know what to typecast each as. cellDescriptors is an array, [0] is referring to the first array group (though there is only one) within that array, and then 11 is the row where the information is stored as a string. Not sure what is best to cast each as? Should [0] just be recast as `[(0 as NSMutableArray)]` and the final `[(11 as String)]`?

Comment: You would typecast `cellDescriptors[0]` to whatever type you know that `cellDescriptors[0]` should be. If it's an `NSArray`, typecast to that. If it's something else, typecast to whatever you expect to be there.

Comment: I used the typecasting to fix the errors (there were ~20 due to this problem when I switched over to swift 3) and understand both why the error was an error and why the fix fixes it, but why was it not a problem in the previous version of swift? Did swift 3 change the default cast to Any, and it used to cast it differently?

Comment: I don't know exactly but I've had a few "how did that ever work?" experiences when moving to Swift 3. It seems to be more strict about certain things.